# About the question "what are the connected components of $\mathbb{R}_l$?"

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

My book asks about the connected components of the topology $\mathbb{R}_l$, which is the one generated by $[a,b)$. As I understood, a component of $X$ is the equivalence class of a point, so for example, given a point $x$, the equivalence class is gonna be the set of all $y$ such that there is a component set that contains $x$ and $y$. So for example, in the $\mathbb{R}$ topology, given a point $x$, all $y$ have the property that there exists a conected subspace containing $x$ and $y$, so there is just one component in $\mathbb{R}$, which is itself, but my book, for the $\mathbb{R}_l$ topology, says that the components are singletons. Why such a difference from my reasoning? Did I do it right for the $\mathbb{R}$ topology? What's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your reasoning, it's just that in $\mathbb R_l$ there is no connected subspace with more than one point. Given two reals $a<b$, consider the subsets $(-\infty,b)$ and $[b,\infty)$. They are both open, they are disjoint, and their union is the whole space, hence any connected subspace is completely contained in exactly one of them. In particular, there is no connected subspace containing both $a$ and $b$.